# Azure and Caching Xml

Tags: azure

I have an XML file that keeps getting updated, however no matter what I do I can't get the updated copy. I always see a cached version of it for a couple of hours. Is there any way to turn off caching for xml? I am using azure website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer I'm assuming you're talking about output caching. In order to disable output caching for *.xml, simply add a [caching profile](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching/profiles/add) to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <caching>
         <profiles>
            <add extension=".xml" policy="DontCache" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />
         </profiles>
      </caching>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```